# Displaying Squares,It looks ugly

Tags: 16.04, unity, themes

I've just switched from 16.10 to 16.04 LTS,i mean i did a clean install now I've installed the osx-Arc shadow theme and some other i am facing a problem,It is displaying squares(I don't know other way to put it,the question.refer the image you will get to know what i am talking about) any help with that ? I know this is not a big Question,But i want to ask because it looks damn ugly like a computer from back in the days.

[Reference Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KV2Q8.png)

Comment: If you don't like the way the theme you installed looks.....

Comment: No,it's not the theme.It is the same scene with all the themes except the inbuilt theme and more over the theme worked fine in 16.10.